# Is it possible to set one job to run at precise hour with anacron

Tags: cron

I set up an `anacron` job:

```
1@hourly 0 name wget https://mydomain.com/actions/controller
```

So it runs hourly but I did not choose the time:
*7:33 then 8:33 then 9:33 ...*

Is it possible to define precisely the time to run as:
*7:00 then 8:00 then 9:00 ...*

Note: my hosting provider give me no choice between `cron` and `anacron`, only `anacron` is available on my virtual server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `anacron` may not be used to schedule jobs for running at exact times like that.  It is best used for making sure that, for example, maintenance script gets run at approximate frequencies, like daily, weekly, or monthly. It does not have a time resolution lower than one day.

Personally, I launch `anacron` from an `@hourly` and a `@reboot` cron job (on my OpenBSD machine that isn't running 24/7), and it takes care of the daily, weekly, and monthly tasks if those tasks needs doing:

```
@hourly /usr/local/sbin/anacron -s
@reboot /usr/local/sbin/anacron -s
```

The `anacrontab`:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
HOME=/var/log

1       1       cron.daily      /bin/sh /etc/daily
7       3       cron.weekly     /bin/sh /etc/weekly
28      5       cron.monthly    /bin/sh /etc/monthly
```

Some versions of `anacron` seems to understand `@daily`, `@weekly`, and `@monthly` (I using version 2.4.3, and its `anacrontab` manual does *not* mention those placeholders, but [this one](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/anacrontab.5.html) does).  However, I haven't been able to find any implementations of `anacron` that supports using `@hourly`.

However, if you run `anacron` hourly, like I do, and if one of its jobs needs executing, then that job will be run *on the hour*, i.e. approximately at 08:00 rather than 08:33. But it won't be run *hourly*.

Comment: Thx great answer. I was talking about hours because my hosting service GANDI is providing anacron with hourly frequence : https://wiki.gandi.net/en/simple/anacron

Answer (score 5):

anacron is just for daily, weekly and monthly, for specific times i would recommend using cron instead.

```
* * * * * *
| | | | | | 
| | | | | +-- Year              (range: 1900-3000)
| | | | +---- Day of the Week   (range: 1-7, 1 standing for Monday)
| | | +------ Month of the Year (range: 1-12)
| | +-------- Day of the Month  (range: 1-31)
| +---------- Hour              (range: 0-23)
+------------ Minute            (range: 0-59)
```

so if you want it to run at 7am you would do, "0 7 * * * * command" this will run at 7am every day, remember that the hour is in military time. 0-23.